# GDB - debug external library, have source code

Tags: gdb, debugging

I am using gdb to debug a package that is using an external library.  I have the source code of the external library.  How do I make gdb load this source code as well?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know if the external library was compiled with the "include debugging symbols" flag set? I assume it was not. If you can recompile with that flag set it will make debugging easier.

Comment: An example using gcc: `gcc -g main.c -g library.h -g library.c -o main`

Answer (score 2):

To make GDB find sources for the library, use the `dir` command. More info [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html).